# How to test this public method using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How can I test this public static method using Mockito?

```
public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode) {
    if (CURRENCY_CODE_USD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)) {
        return US_DOLLAR;
    }
    if (CURRENCY_CODE_HKD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)) {
        return HK_DOLLAR;
    }
    if (CURRENCY_CODE_MYR.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode)) {
        return MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is a static method so I do not see the need of using here Mockito at all. Mockitio mocks mostly an interface and the methods of an interface are never static.

Comment: So, can you please tell how to use mockito in such a simple program with example.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is to use JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: Junit i want to use mainly

Comment: You use Mockito only to mock dependencies. For example your database access in an application should be hidden behind interfaces that can be afterwards mocked in your JUnit tests.

Comment: So i cannot use mockito for this code as example.

Comment: I do not see any use for Mockito in this particular case. The method itself is static and inside this method you do not have any dependencies to another interfaces/classes. This is a fairly simple method that you can test implicitly with JUnit or TestNG assertions.

Comment: And a side note on code quality: consider **not** returning null. Returning null is the first step for NullPointerExceptions to occur. Instead, you should consider if your enum (?) type Currency could have an instance like UNDEFINED_CURRENCY; or something alike. Meaning: most of the time, it is much better to use return "some special non-null value" instead of null.

Comment: How to write a Person test that uses a mock for the address.
@Martin

Answer (score 1):

You want to read about the usage of mocking for unit tests ... as you simply do not any kind of mocking in order to fully test such methods:

Example, a simple JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testGetCurrencyCodeForUSDollar() {
    assertThat(getByCurrencyCode("USD"), is(US_DOLLAR))
```

where:

**assertThat** is the one and only assert that one really needs

**is** is one of many [hamcrest matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html)

Or the other way round: you only need mocking, when your "class under test" is actively using "some other objects" in order to do its job. Then it might be useful, sometimes mandatory that you "replace" "those other objects" with something that you can fully control.

Comment: How to write a Person test that uses a mock for the address. ?